# Unable to get a gallery and sound plugin to work on in an article

Tags: audio, plugins, joomla, gallery

I'm developing a Joomla website at the moment and I really need to have a gallery and a media player as part of an article and a K2 profile. I'm using Joomla 2.5.8

I have download saudioplayer and simple gallery and enabled both plugins but when I put the code {saudioplayer}filename{/saudioplayer} and the same for {gallery} It just returns the text back out to me. Its like its not recognising the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forget to enabled the plugin after the installation check it by going to the following navigation:

```
Extensions->plugin manager->Content - SAudioPlayer
```

and enable it and then check if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have it enabled. To double check I disabled it and then re-enabled it but still doesn't work! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi Thanks again but unfortunately clearing my cache hasn't worked either still haven't sloved this issue. Any other ideas?